# r is undefined, obtain all roles user has

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, roles, discord.js

I am trying to make when the user posts the command, they are able to swap between roles at will. The roles are simply colors for the server I am making it for. The part that is having issues is the first part before the "var args" part. Basically, the part that finds all roles the user is currently in and removes them before moving onto adding the new role is where the problem is.

I got the bot working to add roles. Then I knew I needed to remove all old roles in order for the new color (which might be lower in hierarchy) might not show up.

The error to the code below is "(node:181764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: r is not defined." I took that part right off anidiotsguide. I am learning js as is. Figured this small project would be simple to give me a little experience with discord.js. Apologies if I look like a complete novice. I am. lol Appreciate the help in advance.

```html
bot.on('message', async (message) => {

  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!colorme"))
  if(message.member.roles.some(r => ["blue", "red", "yellow"].includes(r.name)))
  await(message.member.removeRole(r.name));

  {
    var args = message.content.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    console.log(args);
    if(args[1] === "blue")
  {
      var role = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'blue');
      console.log("Role found!");
      message.member.addRole(role.id);
      message.channel.send('Role successfully added!');
  }
  else if(args[1] === 'red')
  {
    addUserRole('red', message);
    message.channel.send('Role successfully added!');
}
else if(args[1] === 'yellow')
  {
    addUserRole('yellow', message);
    message.channel.send('Role successfully added!');

    }
  };
});

function addUserRole(roleName, message)
{
  var role = message.guild.roles.find('name', roleName);
  message.member.addRole(role.id);
  return;
}
```

Comment: What does an example of `message.member.roles` look like? Your `message.member.roles.some(r => ["blue", "red", "yellow"].includes(r.name))` call should work for an array of strings

Comment: I thought it should work too, but it keeps telling me r needs to be defined, but I'm not even sure what it needs to be defined as... The roles that are trying to be found are various colors. I want the bot to essentially reset the roles for the user, then apply the new one. I know how I'd define it when it is looking for a certain role that it is looking to remove, but this server has 26 different color roles. I just want it to see the roles the user has currently, remove it, then add the new one. anidiotsguide didn't elaborate on what r should be for this useage, so I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the .some method not correctly. Take a look at it [**here**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=some).

I used .array for your roles collection of the guildmember, it's the same as the .some method of discord.js (Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSnMS.png)

Try the following code:

```
bot.on('message', async (message) => {

    if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!colorme"))
    message.member.roles.array().some(r => {
        if (["blue", "red", "yellow"].includes(r.name)) {
            message.member.removeRole(r);
        }
    })

    {
      var args = message.content.toLowerCase().split(" ");
      console.log(args);
      if(args[1] === "blue")
    {
        var role = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'blue');
        console.log("Role found!");
        message.member.addRole(role.id);
        message.channel.send('Role successfully added!');
    }
    else if(args[1] === 'red')
    {
      addUserRole('red', message);
      message.channel.send('Role successfully added!');
  }
  else if(args[1] === 'yellow')
    {
      addUserRole('yel', message);
      message.channel.send('Role successfully added!');

      }
    };
  });

  function addUserRole(roleName, message)
  {
    var role = message.guild.roles.find('name', roleName);
    message.member.addRole(role.id);
    return;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179222/discussion-on-answer-by-monkeyyy11-r-is-undefined-obtain-all-roles-user-has).